# Yii2: how to populate a Gridview column using a SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, gridview, yii2

I have a GridView with two columns: Id and Lastname.

The Id columns works great but I have a problem with the Lastname column: I need to execute a simple SQL query `SELECT lastname FROM persons` to complete the Lastname column.

I don't know how to do it. This is what I tried:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        [
            'label' => 'Lastname',
            'value' => function() {
                $myQuery = 'SELECT lastname FROM persons';
                return = Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand($myQuery)->queryAll(); // Problem here.
            }
        ]
    ]
)] ?>
```

My DataProvider of my PersonsSearch.php model (is it possible to add my sql query here?):

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Persons::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'id' => SORT_ASC
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'id', $this->id]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use an SqlDataProvider as mentioned in the guides?  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers#sql-data-provider

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in `$dataprovider`? If it is loaded with objects from persons table, you can call it like `id` - `lastname` or you can call it like that:

```
[
            'label' => 'Lastname',
            'value' => function($model) {
                 return $model->lastname;
            }
]
```

In PersonsSearch.php

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id'], 'integer'],
        [['lastname'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

and search function

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Persons::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'id' => SORT_ASC
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'id', $this->id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'lastname', $this->lastname]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Other way when you have

```
 [
                'label' => 'Lastname',
                'value' => function($model) {
                     return $model->getLastName();
                }
    ]
```

Create function in `Persons.php` model with name `getLastName()`

```
public function getLastName(){
   $myQuery = 'SELECT lastname FROM persons'; //maybe you have where condition "where id = {$this->id}" ?
   $result = Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand($myQuery)->queryOne();
   if($result){
        return $result['lastname'];
   }
}
```

If you have many rows, then use `queryAll()` and foreach the result.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to say that id is in the model but lastname is not.

Comment: Would you show how you load $dataprovider? Do you use PersonsSearch.php model?

Comment: Your field lastname is in table persons, so Persons.php model use persons database table. PersonsSearch.php is extended from Persons.php. So you can add prperty lastnaem just like id

Comment: Actually my SQL query is very more complex (it has join, sum and group by). I simplify it with a simple Select to show just an example).

Comment: Well, use the relation name - 'value' => function($model){ return $model->relName->lastname;}

Comment: I'm Sorry but I don't understand. I don't have a model with lastname. I only have my SQL query. Else I can make a database view I then can generate the model with Gii.

Comment: Yes, if you can give more information about database.. or you can see updated post for sql function